# An issue with the average function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a very annoying issue with the average function.

I am doing averages where sometimes I have no data in a column (column C in the picture below). It then writes a 0 but still considers it as a number to average which is not convinient at all.

Is it possible to get the average so that when it is a 0 it does not countit in the average. Otherwise all my data is false.

Thank you for your help!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Is it possible average so that 0 is excluded?

Use `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS` instead of `AVERAGE`:

To exclude `0`:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A50,">0")
```

To exclude blank cells:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A50,"<>""")
```

To exclude `0` **and** blanks cells:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A50,A1:A50,">0",A1:A50,"<>""")
```

Note:

- `AVERAGEIF` and `AVERAGEIFS` were introduced in Excel 2007
- For earlier versions of Excel see [An Average that Excludes Zero Values](http://excel.tips.net/T007727_An_Average_that_Excludes_Zero_Values.html)

---

#### An Average that Excludes Zero Values (Excel 2007 and 2010)

> Veronica knows how to use the `AVERAGE` function to determine the
>   average of a range of values. She would like to have the average
>   determined based on the non-zero values in the range, however.
>
> The worksheet function most suited to this purpose is to use
>   `AVERAGEIF`. You can use it in this manner:
>
> ```
> =AVERAGEIF(A1:A50,">0")
> ```
>
> This function only includes in the average those cells that contain
>   values greater than zero. If you want to also exclude blank cells, you
>   should use the `AVERAGEIFS` function. This function differs from
>   `AVERAGEIF` in that it allows you to specify multiple criteria that
>   indicate which cells to average.
>
> ```
> =AVERAGEIFS(A1:A50,A1:A50,">0",A1:A50,"<>""")
> ```
>
> Of course, if you want to approach the problem "old school" (without
>   using `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS`), then there are several ways you
>   can proceed. The first is to remember how an average is calculated. It
>   is defined as the sum of a range of values divided by the number of
>   items in the range. Thus, you could figure the exclusionary average by
>   simply making sure that the denominator (the number you are dividing
>   by) does not include any zero values. For instance:
>
> ```
> =SUM(A1:A50)/COUNTIF(A1:A50,"<>0")
> ```
>
> This approach uses the `COUNTIF` function to determine the number of
>   cells in the range `(A1:A50)` that don't contain zero. If this range
>   contains not only zeros but also blank cells, and you don't want the
>   blank cells figured into the result, then you need to use a more
>   complex formula:
>
> ```
> =SUM(A1:A50)/(COUNTIF(A1:A50,"<>0")-COUNTBLANK(A1:A50)- (COUNTA(A1:A50)-COUNT(A1:A50)))
> ```
>
> The `COUNTIF` function counts cells that do not explicitly evaluate to
>   0, but it will count blank and text cells. The `COUNTBLANK` term
>   adjusts for the blank cells and the difference between `COUNTA` and
>   `COUNT` adjusts the total count for cells that contain text.
>
> Of course you can also use an array formula to do your calculation:
>
> ```
> =AVERAGE(IF(A1:A50<>0,A1:A50))
> ```
>
> Remember that array formulas need to be entered by using the
>   combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This
>   array formula also excludes blanks or cells containing text.
>
> All in all it is easier to use the `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS`
>   functions.

Source [An Average that Excludes Zero Values](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T007729_An_Average_that_Excludes_Zero_Values.html)